# How to read sFlow?

Tags: monitoring, ddos, brocade, attacks, sflow

We currently have a very large outbound DDOS Attack coming from one of our machines which is on a Brocade switch and monitored by PRTG. I am looking at the sFlow v5 8 sensor and see Top Talkers and Top Connections, but cannot make heads or tails of these live circle graphs. Can anyone please shed some light on how I can figure out what IP this traffic is originating from?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure that sFlow is the right tool (protocol) for real time debugging...do you have a Firewall with logs to analyse ?

Comment: Are you asking how to interpret the sFlow data itself or how PRTG displays it (the live circle graphs part)?

Comment: Really just trying to figure out what IP this traffic is coming from so I can null-route it for now. When I click the switch in PRTG it shows that its coming from GigabitEthernet1/2/1 but I have no idea what that is. Our network engineer whose not available at the moment has shown similar work using these sFlow graphs but I am having trouble interpreting them

Comment: If you know the Switch/Interface where the DDOS comes from, you can block it immediatly by either shutdown the switch port or get the associated ip from the port, and block it at FW side. Analyse will come later (assuming i have interpreted your post as an emergency).

Comment: I am connected to the switch via SSH but the only guide the Network Admin left for me is instructions to null an IP Address. Any idea how to shut off a port from a Brocade switch?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't mention which `Brocade` switch this was but I suspect it's one of their `FastIron/ICX` family so here is how to "shut off" or disable a port on a `Brocade FastIron` or `ICX switch`.

To disable port 8 of a Brocade device, enter the following.

```
device(config)
# interface ethernet 8
device(config-if-e1000-8)# disable
```

I got it from the following if you want to see more:

- http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/FI_08010_ADMIN/GUID-D053A670-686E-4821-B7F5-51230C0C6BC1.html

If you have a different `Brocade` switch, reply back with the details and I'll reply again.